# openvpn connection only for specific websites

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn, openvpn

i am under windows 7 and using the openvpn client gui. I want to use the openvpn connection only for a specific website. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have full access (root/sudo/Administrator, that is) to the OpenVPN client, you can manipulate routing table entries to suit your needs. 
OpenVPN `redirect-gateway` directive adds routes to your system routing table, you can do the same.

Bear in mind, however, that your VPN was designed not to allow split tunneling and doing so may violate your organization's security policy.

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly do i do? Because the example at openvpn.net describes only how to tunnel all the traffic in a split tunnel connection and not, how to use openvpn full tunnel only for one website and for the rest the usual dsl connection.

Comment: What is happening after VPN link is established: default route is set to gateway on VPN network. What you want: default route back to _your_ router and another route, possibly, but not necessary "host route", to the specific website you mentioned via VPN gateway. `route print` command will show you the routing table. `route` without arguments will show the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Typically OpenVPN is set up with split tunneling. You (or your IT service team) have to do extra configuration to route all traffic though the VPN gateway. See this link: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect

Naturally, if that particular website your want to access is inside the VPN network then you access it though OpenVPN connection and all the other traffic goes through your default router.
Was that your concern?

Comment: Unfortunatly i have no access to the openvpn server. The config file i have, does full-tunneling, so that all the traffic is sent through the openvpn tunnel. Since i only need to access one website, through open vpn i would like to configure the openvpn client i a way so that only this one website is accessed through open vpn. I hope this makes it clearer.